# Undefined offset: 0

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get simple fb graph data and load that into a table with php, but somehow i receive 4 same error messages why so ever and I dont know what they mean.

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in index.php on line 52

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in index.php on line 55

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in index.php on line 59

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in index.php on line 60

Here are the lines where the error / warnings appear ..

```
        echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>";
    //count the number of events
    $events_count = count($obj['data']);

     for($x=0; $x<$events_count; $x++){
        //fb events will be here
     }
     echo"</table>";
     $start_date = date( 'l, F d, Y', strtotime($obj['data'][$x]['start_time']));

    // in my case, I had to subtract 9 hours to sync the time set in facebook
    $start_time = date('g:i a', strtotime($obj['data'][$x]['start_time']) - 60 * 60 * 9);

    $pic_big = isset($obj['data'][$x]['cover']['source']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['cover']['source'] : "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/picture?type=large";

    $eid = $obj['data'][$x]['id'];
    $name = $obj['data'][$x]['name'];
    $description = isset($obj['data'][$x]['description']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['description'] : "";

    // place
    $place_name = isset($obj['data'][$x]['place']['name']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['place']['name'] : "";
    $city = isset($obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['city']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['city'] : "";
    $country = isset($obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['country']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['country'] : "";
    $zip = isset($obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['zip']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['zip'] : "";

    $location="";

    if($place_name && $city && $country && $zip){
        $location="{$place_name}, {$city}, {$country}, {$zip}";
    }else{
        $location="Location not set or event data is too old.";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td rowspan='6' style='width:20em;'>";
        echo "<img src='{$pic_big}' width='200px' />";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='width:15em;'>What:</td>";
    echo "<td><b>{$name}</b></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>When:</td>";
    echo "<td>{$start_date} at {$start_time}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Where:</td>";
    echo "<td>{$location}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Description:</td>";
    echo "<td>{$description}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Facebook Link:</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/events/{$eid}/' target='_blank'>View on Facebook</a>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Thanks for help and fast answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined offset PHP error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508215/undefined-offset-php-error)

Comment: Please post your code not snapshot of code. Second copy your into loop.

Comment: @Hassan update my question

Comment: @TamoDaleko I have added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31783698/4939819).

Answer (score 0):

Add your code inside loop.

Try

```
<?php

    echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>";
    //count the number of events
    $events_count = count($obj['data']);

    for($x=0; $x<$events_count; $x++)
    {
        //fb events will be here

        $start_date = date( 'l, F d, Y', strtotime($obj['data'][$x]['start_time']));

        // in my case, I had to subtract 9 hours to sync the time set in facebook
        $start_time = date('g:i a', strtotime($obj['data'][$x]['start_time']) - 60 * 60 * 9);

        $pic_big = isset($obj['data'][$x]['cover']['source']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['cover']['source'] : "https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/picture?type=large";

        $eid = $obj['data'][$x]['id'];
        $name = $obj['data'][$x]['name'];
        $description = isset($obj['data'][$x]['description']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['description'] : "";

        // place
        $place_name = isset($obj['data'][$x]['place']['name']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['place']['name'] : "";
        $city = isset($obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['city']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['city'] : "";
        $country = isset($obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['country']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['country'] : "";
        $zip = isset($obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['zip']) ? $obj['data'][$x]['place']['location']['zip'] : "";

        $location="";

        if($place_name && $city && $country && $zip){
            $location="{$place_name}, {$city}, {$country}, {$zip}";
        }else{
            $location="Location not set or event data is too old.";
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td rowspan='6' style='width:20em;'>";
            echo "<img src='{$pic_big}' width='200px' />";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style='width:15em;'>What:</td>";
        echo "<td><b>{$name}</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>When:</td>";
        echo "<td>{$start_date} at {$start_time}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Where:</td>";
        echo "<td>{$location}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Description:</td>";
        echo "<td>{$description}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Facebook Link:</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/events/{$eid}/' target='_blank'>View on Facebook</a>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo"</table>";
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but there is no data displayed now .. not even the table

Comment: how can i track this waring ?

Comment: @TamoDaleko I got it. Please `var_dump($obj['data']);` to see what is in `$obj['data'];` I think there is nothing.

Comment: I have done the  var_dump($obj['data']); before the for loop then i receive this array(0) { }

Comment: @TamoDaleko yes, there is not data in your code `$obj['data]`. Now check why there is no data in `$obj['data']`

Answer (score -1):

You should close `for` correctly.
You can't use `$x` var out of `for`.

Comment: No. Just put your code into `for` loop. See Line 50

Comment: how do you mean that  ?

Answer (score -1):

Your `for` loop is:

```
for($x=0; $x<$events_counts; $x++) {
// fb events will be here
}
// other code below
// $x is not available here!
```

So, basically you have `}` and you're trying to access `$x` which is declarated (unless it's global) in scope of `for`, but it doesn't exists below closing bracket. Put your code in `for` loop and it should works.