# Getting Undefined offset: 2 error on foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the code :

```
        foreach ($test_scores as $score) {
        switch ($score['name']) {
            case 'LE-TOD':
                $le_tod = $score['banding'];
                $le_tod_desc = $score["result_desc"];
                if($score['std_score'] == 0) {
                    $le_tod_small = $scoring['tod']['no_pref_bottom'];
                }
                else {
                    $le_tod_small = $scoring['tod']['pref_bottom'].$score['banding']; 
                }
                break;
```

This is where I get the error message :

```
    public static function generateLSPReportFile($dataInput, $auto_download = true)
{
    $file_type = $dataInput['file_type'];
    $test_type_id = $dataInput['test_type_id'];
    $he_she = array('male' => 'He', 'female' => 'She');
    $his_her = array('male' => 'his', 'female' => 'her');

    $candidate = \Candidate::where('id',$dataInput['candidate_id'])->first();

    if(!$candidate)
        return;

    $candidate = $candidate->toArray();
    $candidate_name = $candidate['first_name'].' '.$candidate['last_name'];

    $order = \Order::with('client')->find($dataInput['order_id']);

    if(!$order)
        return;

    $client = $order->client;
    $order = $order->toArray();

    //for test dates
    $order_candidate = \OrderCandidate::candidateId($dataInput['candidate_id'])->orderId($dataInput['order_id'])->first()->toArray();

    $order_tests = \OrderCandidateTest::orderCandidateId($order_candidate['id'])
                        ->status(\Config::get('kcg.candidate_test_status_taken'))
                        ->testId($dataInput['test_id'])
                        ->with(array('test' => function($query){
                            $query->select(['id', 'name', 'description', 'abbreviation']);
                        }));

    $tests_scores = \OrderCandidateTestScore::orderId($dataInput['order_id'])
                        ->candidateId($dataInput['candidate_id'])
                        ->testId($dataInput['test_id'])
                        ->with(array('test' => function($query){
                            $query->select(['id', 'name', 'description', 'test_type_id']);
                        }));
    $test_type = TestType::find($test_type_id);
    $test_scores = $tests_scores->orderBy('sequence_no')->get()->toArray();
    $order_tests = $order_tests->get()->toArray();

    if(!$order_tests)
        return;

    if(!$tests_scores)
        return;
```

It posted an error : ErrorException Undefined offset: 2. I'm really not sure what's causing this.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help me. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about Craft CMS, but a general PHP related question and should be asked in StackOverflow.

Comment: Agreed with @carlcs. Even if this is happening within the context of a Craft plugin, it's strictly a PHP issue. Migrating to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the `Undefined offset` message would be triggered by **trying to access an array key which doesn't exist**.

It seems that your code example might not actually be showing the part that triggered the error... In your case, I would expect the code to show something like `$var[2]`, where the array does not actually contain an index of `2`.

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508215/undefined-offset-php-error) for a clearer representation of what that error means.

Comment: I believe this array statement is wrong and is causing all of it?

 'noise_level' => array (
  
  'detail_id' => '88',
  'detail_id_adult' => '94',

  'message' => array (
   'Not affected by noise level',
   'Prefers quiet environment'
  )
  
 ),

Comment: I solved it. Thank you for the advice and the link, 

 'noise_level' => array (
  
  'detail_id' => '88',
  'detail_id_adult' => '94',

  'message' => array (
  '1' => 'Not affected by noise level',
  '2' => 'Prefers quiet environment'
  )
  
 ),

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark this answer as "accepted" (the green checkmark) if it did the trick for you. :)