# Avoiding undefined offset error

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I have following function

```
function getSum($array){
    if(is_array($array)) {
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
            $sum += $value;
        }
    } else{
        $sum = $array;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

And I'm using it like this

```
$teams = array();
$teams[1]['AREA I']['blue'] = 30;
$teams[1]['AREA I']['green'] = 25;
$teams[1]['AREA II']['blue'] = 15;
$teams[2]['AREA I']['blue'] = 40;

echo getSum($teams); //output: 110
echo getSum($teams[1]); //output: 70
echo getSum($teams[1]['AREA I']); //output: 55
echo getSum($teams[1]['AREA I']['blue']); //output: 30
```

How to avoid error *Undefined offset* when using like `getSum($teams[2]['AREA IV']` (key AREA IV not set)? In this case I want that function returns zero.

Comment: Add a check if the offset is set or not. `isset` or `empty` depending on conditions.

Comment: To add on to what @Sougata said, you could use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) with `empty`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined offset PHP error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508215/undefined-offset-php-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error occurs before the *getSum* function is called, there is no way you can change that function so that it would work.

However, if you are willing to change the arguments that are passed to *getSum*, you could get around that. You could pass the array without further keys specifications (to avoid the potential error) and specify the key(s) as a second argument. Then leave it to *getSum* to try to get to that value if it exists, like this:

```
function getSum($array, $path = array()){
    // process second argument:
    foreach ($path as $key) {
        if (!is_array($array) || !isset($array[$key])) {
            return 0; // key does not exist, return 0
        }
        $array = $array[$key];
    }
    if(is_array($array)) {
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
            $sum += $value;
        }
    } else{
        $sum = $array;
    }
    return $sum;
}

$teams = array();
$teams[1]['AREA I']['blue'] = 30;
$teams[1]['AREA I']['green'] = 25;
$teams[1]['AREA II']['blue'] = 15;
$teams[2]['AREA I']['blue'] = 40;

// pass an optional 2nd argument:    
echo getSum($teams); //output: 110
echo getSum($teams, [1]); //output: 70
echo getSum($teams, [1,'AREA I']); //output: 55
echo getSum($teams, [1,'AREA I','blue']); //output: 30
echo getSum($teams, [2, 'AREA IV']); // no error, output: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer! It's working perfectly.