# Notice (8): Undefined offset: 2 [APP/View/Helper/CounterHelper.php

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.8

I am novice in cakephp and I use version 2.8, I would like to add a counter of visit on my homepage, nevertheless I obtain the following errors:

```
Notice (8): Undefined offset: 2 [APP/View/Helper/CounterHelper.php, line 157]
Notice (8): Undefined offset: 2 [APP/View/Helper/CounterHelper.php, line 186]
```

I put you the code end concerned:

```
 //Start get detail
        foreach ( $data as $value ){
            $temp = explode ("/", $value['Counter']['date_visit']);
            if ( $temp[0] == $this->Time['mday'] && $temp[1] == $this->Time['mon'] ){
                //Get user online
                if ( $newTime - $value['Counter']['time'] < $this->TimeOut )
                    ++$this->User_Online;
            }

  line 157 ====>  if ( $this->Time['year'] == $temp[2] ){

                //Get today static
                if ( $this_date == $temp[0] )
                    ++$this->Total_Today;

                //Get this month static
                if ( $this_month == $temp['1'] )
                    ++$this->Total_Month;
            }

        }

        //For previous

        $prev_date = $this->Time['mday'] - 1;
        $prev_mon = $this->Time['mon'] - 1;

        if ( $prev_date < 1){
            $prev_date = 30;
            $prev_mon -= 1;
        }

        if ( $prev_mon < 1)
            $prev_mon = 12;

        foreach ($data as $value){
            $temp = explode ("/", $value['Counter']['date_visit']);

  line 186  ====>  if ( $this->Time['year'] == $temp[2] ){
                if ( $prev_date == $temp[0] )
                    ++$this->Total_Yesterday;
                if ( $prev_mon == $temp['1'] )
                    ++$this->Total_Mon_Prev;
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance for your answer.

p.s:  the lines concerned are: line 157 and line 186

Comment: This has nothing to do with CakePHP. You might want to start by learning how to lookup errors in the language documentation. ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508215/undefined-offset-php-error/21793407#21793407

Comment: It means that second element is not available in your $temp array. You can check values of $temp array using pr($temp);

Comment: To help it is important to see what is inside the $data

Comment: write before your code snipped the following line and show us what the output is:
debug($data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following code before the lines indicated

```
if (is_array($temp))
```