# I get "ErrorException in SteamAuth.php line 206: Undefined offset: 1"

Tags: php, steam

I want to make SteamLogin on my website but try to login I get

> "ErrorException in SteamAuth.php line 206:
>   Undefined offset: 1"
>   "array('matches' => array())) in SteamAuth.php line 206"

```
$this->steamId = is_numeric($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : 0;
```

Comment: `$this->steamId = isset($matches[1]) && is_numeric($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : 0;` should fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined offset PHP error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508215/undefined-offset-php-error)

Comment: now i have a new error:ErrorException in SteamAuth.php line 221:
Undefined offset: 0           Here is the full Code

Comment: ErrorException in SteamAuth.php line 221:
Undefined offset: 0

Comment: $this->steamInfo = new SteamInfo($json["response"]["players"][0]);

Comment: This is the same problem and the same way to solve

Comment: [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) helps a lot debugging

Comment: okay what exactly is the problem how can i sole it always